Varnish redirect Issue
I have an nginx vhost for a magento instance in a dedicated server
nginx.conf
user  www-data;
worker_processes  auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 50000;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  20000;
    multi_accept        on;
    use                 epoll;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    autoindex       off;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 25;
    client_body_timeout 15;
    client_header_timeout 15;
    send_timeout 15;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 64M;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    client_header_buffer_size 16k;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
#    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 32k;
    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    
   
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    log_format  main  '$http_cf_connecting_ip [ $http_x_forwarded_for] [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main ;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

        ## Cache open FD
        open_file_cache max=50000 inactive=30s;
        open_file_cache_valid 30s;
        open_file_cache_min_uses 2;

## New settings

    gzip on;
    gzip_vary   on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_static on;
    gzip_min_length   1400;
    gzip_buffers      16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_proxied    any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/javascript  application/x-javascript application/xml application/xml+rss application/ecmascript application/json image/svg+xml ;


    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##
    
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

vhost configuration
upstream fastcgi_backend {
  server   unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    server_name example.com www.example.gr 123.123.123.123;

    listen 8080;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /home/public_html;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain-access.log main ;
    access_log  /dev/null;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/doamin-error.log ;

    include /home/public_html/nginx.conf;


#    Cloudflare
     include /etc/nginx/conf.d/cloudflare.conf;
     

# apply ratebot rules
    limit_req zone=ratebot_soft nodelay;
    limit_req zone=ratebot_medium nodelay;
    limit_req zone=ratebot_hard nodelay;

    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=604800,  public";
    add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;

# Nginx Bad Bot Blocker Includes
# REPO: https://github.com/mitchellkrogza/nginx-ultimate-bad-bot-blocker
##
     include /etc/nginx/bots.d/ddos.conf;
     include /etc/nginx/bots.d/blockbots.conf;


}

And final magento nginx configuration
root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

index index.php;
autoindex off;
charset UTF-8;
error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;
#add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";


# Deny access to sensitive files
location /.user.ini {
    deny all;
}

# PHP entry point for setup application
location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
    deny all;
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;

        fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=600";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;
#       fastcgi_param HTTPS $HTTPS_FORWARD;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

# PHP entry point for update application
location ~* ^/update($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;

    location ~ ^/update/index.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Deny everything but index.php
    location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

location / {

    # el_GR redirect
    rewrite "^/(?!admin|el_gr|sitemap|stripe|rest|soap|graphql|index\.php)(.*)" /el_gr/$1 permanent;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    add_header Host $host;
    port_in_redirect off;                   # el_GR redirect
    add_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    add_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    add_header Ssl-Offloaded $scheme;
}

location /pub/ {
    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
        deny all;
    }
    alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /static/ {
    # Uncomment the following line in production mode
    expires max;

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/static/version {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|html|json|webp)$ {
        access_log off;
        
        
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header 'X-Frame-Options' 'ALLOW-FROM *';
#        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;
        include /etc/nginx/magento2-cors.conf;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header 'X-Frame-Options' 'ALLOW-FROM *';
#        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;
        include /etc/nginx/magento2-cors.conf;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    include /etc/nginx/magento2-cors.conf;
}

location /media/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|webp)$ {
        access_log off;
        
        
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header 'X-Frame-Options' 'ALLOW-FROM *';
#        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        include /etc/nginx/magento2-cors.conf;
        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header 'X-Frame-Options' 'ALLOW-FROM *';
#        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        include /etc/nginx/magento2-cors.conf;
        expires    off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/customer/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/downloadable/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/import/ {
    deny all;
}
location /errors/ {
    location ~* \.xml$ {
        deny all;
    }
}

# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ ^/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check|bridge_JZOpQnn5)\.php$ {
    
    set $cors_origin "*";

   
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $cors_origin always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'POST, GET, OPTIONS' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,X-Cache-Hash' always;
      ### Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
      add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
      add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
      add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
      return 204;
    }

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $cors_origin always;

    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 32k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;


    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
location ~* \.(js)$ {
        access_log off;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header X-Asset "yes";
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'X-Frame-Options' 'ALLOW-FROM *';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
#        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
#        expires max;
        expires +1y;
    }

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 64 32k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/xml+rss
    image/svg+xml;
gzip_vary on;

# Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't match)
location ~* (\.php$|\.phtml$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
    deny all;
}

Now I am trying to redirect in Varnish vcl file all urls from http to https
I am using this rule:
sub vcl_recv {

    if (!req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {

if(std.port(server.ip) == 443) {
    set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "https";
} else {
    set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "http";
    }
}

if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto != "https") {
set req.http.location = "https://" + req.http.host + req.url;
return(synth(301));
}

if (!req.http.Ssl-offloaded) {

if(std.port(server.ip) == 443) {
    set req.http.http-ssl-offloaded="https";
} else {
    set req.http.http-ssl-offloaded="http";
    }
}

if (req.http.Ssl-offloaded != "https") {
set req.http.location = "https://" + req.http.host + req.url;
return(synth(301));
}

and lower this
sub vcl_synth {
  if (resp.status == 301 || resp.status == 302) {
    set resp.http.location = req.http.location;
    set resp.status = 301;
    return (deliver);
    }
}

It works fine when requests are with domain name. Also it redirects fine www to non www as needed
But it doesn't work with local ip. All requests which are made to server's ip are not redirect to domain.
Nginx is there but the redirect must be done with varnish because varnish is in port 80 and TLS termination was made with Hitch
Output of varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/'"
<< Request  >> 1868411
-   Begin          req 1868410 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1729790420.336435 0.000000 0.000000
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/2.0
-   Timestamp      Req: 1729790420.336435 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       13.123.123.123 60303 uds
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/2.0
-   ReqHeader      scheme: https
-   ReqHeader      host: local.ip
-   ReqHeader      sec-fetch-dest: document
-   ReqHeader      user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/18.0.1 Safari/605.1.15
-   ReqHeader      accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
-   ReqHeader      sec-fetch-site: none
-   ReqHeader      sec-fetch-mode: navigate
-   ReqHeader      accept-language: en-GB,en;q=0.9
-   ReqHeader      priority: u=0, i
-   ReqHeader      accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      cookie: _ga=GA1.1.688454023.1728876919; _ga_2LPR9Q1R58=GS1.1.1729790281.5.1.1729790391.0.0.234830748; _gcl_au=1.1.845148297.1728876919; __kla_id=eyJjaWQiOiJZV00wTXpKaE0yTXROR1JoTlMwME5HTXhMV0k1TXpFdFlXUmhNamswTnpNeE1HVTUiLCIkcmVmZXJyZXIiOnsidHMiOjE3Mjg4N
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 13.123.123.123
-   ReqHeader      Via: 1.1 DOMAIN (Varnish/7.5)
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqUnset       host: local.ip
-   ReqHeader      host: local.ip
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqHeader      grace: none
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqUnset       accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   HitMiss        688879 86371.062500
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 2425988 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1729790420.336892 0.000457 0.000457
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     301
-   RespReason     Moved Permanently
-   RespHeader     Server: nginx
-   RespHeader     Date: Thu, 24 Oct 2024 17:20:20 GMT
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html
-   RespHeader     Location: http://local.ip/el_gr/
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: max-age=604800,  public
-   RespHeader     Content-Encoding: gzip
-   RespHeader     Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 1868411
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 DOMAIN (Varnish/7.5)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespHeader     X-Magento-Cache-Debug: UNCACHEABLE
-   RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache
-   RespHeader     Expires: -1
-   RespUnset      Cache-Control: max-age=604800,  public
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
-   RespUnset      Age: 0
-   RespUnset      Server: nginx
-   RespUnset      X-Varnish: 1868411
-   RespUnset      Via: 1.1 DOMAIN (Varnish/7.5)
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1729790420.336907 0.000472 0.000015
-   Filters
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 125
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/2.0
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1729790420.336926 0.000490 0.000018
-   ReqAcct        621 0 621 218 125 343
-   End
**  << BeReq    >> 2425988
--  Begin          bereq 1868411 fetch
--  VCL_use        boot
--  Timestamp      Start: 1729790420.336517 0.000000 0.000000
--  BereqMethod    GET
--  BereqURL       /
--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/2.0
--  BereqHeader    scheme: https
--  BereqHeader    sec-fetch-dest: document
--  BereqHeader    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/18.0.1 Safari/605.1.15
--  BereqHeader    accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
--  BereqHeader    sec-fetch-site: none
--  BereqHeader    sec-fetch-mode: navigate
--  BereqHeader    accept-language: en-GB,en;q=0.9
--  BereqHeader    priority: u=0, i
--  BereqHeader    cookie: _ga=GA1.1.688454023.1728876919; _ga_2LPR9Q1R58=GS1.1.1729790281.5.1.1729790391.0.0.234830748; _gcl_au=1.1.845148297.1728876919; __kla_id=eyJjaWQiOiJZV00wTXpKaE0yTXROR1JoTlMwME5HTXhMV0k1TXpFdFlXUmhNamswTnpNeE1HVTUiLCIkcmVmZXJyZXIiOnsidHMiOjE3Mjg4N
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 13.123.123.123
--  BereqHeader    Via: 1.1 DOMAIN (Varnish/7.5)
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
--  BereqHeader    host: local.ip
--  BereqHeader    grace: none
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
--  BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 2425988
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
--  VCL_return     fetch
--  Timestamp      Fetch: 1729790420.336528 0.000010 0.000010
--  Timestamp      Connected: 1729790420.336531 0.000013 0.000002
--  BackendOpen    56 default 127.0.0.1 8080 127.0.0.1 43940 reuse
--  Timestamp      Bereq: 1729790420.336555 0.000038 0.000024
--  BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
--  BerespStatus   301
--  BerespReason   Moved Permanently
--  BerespHeader   Server: nginx
--  BerespHeader   Date: Thu, 24 Oct 2024 17:20:20 GMT
--  BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html
--  BerespHeader   Content-Length: 162
--  BerespHeader   Location: http://local.ip/el_gr/
--  BerespHeader   Connection: keep-alive
--  BerespHeader   Cache-Control: max-age=604800,  public
--  Timestamp      Beresp: 1729790420.336800 0.000282 0.000244
--  TTL            RFC 604800 10 0 1729790420 1729790420 1729790420 0 604800 cacheable
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
--  TTL            VCL 604800 10 0 1729790420 cacheable
--  TTL            VCL 604800 259200 0 1729790420 cacheable
--  TTL            VCL 604800 259200 0 1729790420 uncacheable
--  TTL            VCL 86400 259200 0 1729790420 uncacheable
--  VCL_return     deliver
--  Timestamp      Process: 1729790420.336816 0.000298 0.000015
--  Filters         esi_gzip
--  BerespUnset    Content-Length: 162
--  BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
--  BerespHeader   Vary: Accept-Encoding
--  Storage        malloc Transient
--  Fetch_Body     3 length -
--  Gzip           G F E 162 125 80 920 930
--  BackendClose   56 default recycle
--  Timestamp      BerespBody: 1729790420.336890 0.000372 0.000074
--  Length         125
--  BereqAcct      1002 0 1002 237 162 399
--  End

*   << Request  >> 1868412
-   Begin          req 1868410 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1729790420.342215 0.000000 0.000000
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/2.0
-   Timestamp      Req: 1729790420.342215 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       13.123.123.123 60303 uds
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/2.0
-   ReqHeader      scheme: https
-   ReqHeader      host: local.ip
-   ReqHeader      sec-fetch-dest: document
-   ReqHeader      user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/18.0.1 Safari/605.1.15
-   ReqHeader      accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
-   ReqHeader      sec-fetch-site: none
-   ReqHeader      sec-fetch-mode: navigate
-   ReqHeader      accept-language: en-GB,en;q=0.9
-   ReqHeader      priority: u=0, i
-   ReqHeader      accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      cookie: _ga=GA1.1.688454023.1728876919; _ga_2LPR9Q1R58=GS1.1.1729790281.5.1.1729790391.0.0.234830748; _gcl_au=1.1.845148297.1728876919; __kla_id=eyJjaWQiOiJZV00wTXpKaE0yTXROR1JoTlMwME5HTXhMV0k1TXpFdFlXUmhNamswTnpNeE1HVTUiLCIkcmVmZXJyZXIiOnsidHMiOjE3Mjg4N
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 89.210.251.24
-   ReqHeader      Via: 1.1 DOMAIN (Varnish/7.5)
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqUnset       host: local.ip
-   ReqHeader      host: local.ip
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqHeader      grace: none
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqUnset       accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   HitMiss        2425988 86399.992188
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 2425989 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1729790420.342512 0.000296 0.000296
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     301
-   RespReason     Moved Permanently
-   RespHeader     Server: nginx
-   RespHeader     Date: Thu, 24 Oct 2024 17:20:20 GMT
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html
-   RespHeader     Location: http://local.ip/el_gr/
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: max-age=604800,  public
-   RespHeader     Content-Encoding: gzip
-   RespHeader     Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 1868412
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 DOMAIN (Varnish/7.5)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespHeader     X-Magento-Cache-Debug: UNCACHEABLE
-   RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache
-   RespHeader     Expires: -1
-   RespUnset      Cache-Control: max-age=604800,  public
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
-   RespUnset      Age: 0
-   RespUnset      Server: nginx
-   RespUnset      X-Varnish: 1868412
-   RespUnset      Via: 1.1 DOMAIN (Varnish/7.5)
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1729790420.342517 0.000302 0.000005
-   Filters
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 125
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/2.0
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1729790420.342530 0.000314 0.000012
-   ReqAcct        21 0 21 218 125 343
-   End
**  << BeReq    >> 2425989
--  Begin          bereq 1868412 fetch
--  VCL_use        boot
--  Timestamp      Start: 1729790420.342253 0.000000 0.000000
--  BereqMethod    GET
--  BereqURL       /
--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/2.0
--  BereqHeader    scheme: https
--  BereqHeader    sec-fetch-dest: document
--  BereqHeader    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/18.0.1 Safari/605.1.15
--  BereqHeader    accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
--  BereqHeader    sec-fetch-site: none
--  BereqHeader    sec-fetch-mode: navigate
--  BereqHeader    accept-language: en-GB,en;q=0.9
--  BereqHeader    priority: u=0, i
--  BereqHeader    cookie: _ga=GA1.1.688454023.1728876919; _ga_2LPR9Q1R58=GS1.1.1729790281.5.1.1729790391.0.0.234830748; _gcl_au=1.1.845148297.1728876919; __kla_id=eyJjaWQiOiJZV00wTXpKaE0yTXROR1JoTlMwME5HTXhMV0k1TXpFdFlXUmhNamswTnpNeE1HVTUiLCIkcmVmZXJyZXIiOnsidHMiOjE3Mjg4N
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 13.123.123.123
--  BereqHeader    Via: 1.1 DOMAIN (Varnish/7.5)
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
--  BereqHeader    host: local.ip
--  BereqHeader    grace: none
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
--  BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 2425989
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
--  VCL_return     fetch
--  Timestamp      Fetch: 1729790420.342258 0.000005 0.000005
--  Timestamp      Connected: 1729790420.342259 0.000005 0.000000
--  BackendOpen    56 default 127.0.0.1 8080 127.0.0.1 43940 reuse
--  Timestamp      Bereq: 1729790420.342275 0.000021 0.000015
--  BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
--  BerespStatus   301
--  BerespReason   Moved Permanently
--  BerespHeader   Server: nginx
--  BerespHeader   Date: Thu, 24 Oct 2024 17:20:20 GMT
--  BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html
--  BerespHeader   Content-Length: 162
--  BerespHeader   Location: http://local.ip/el_gr/
--  BerespHeader   Connection: keep-alive
--  BerespHeader   Cache-Control: max-age=604800,  public
--  Timestamp      Beresp: 1729790420.342457 0.000204 0.000182
--  TTL            RFC 604800 10 0 1729790420 1729790420 1729790420 0 604800 cacheable
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
--  TTL            VCL 604800 10 0 1729790420 cacheable
--  TTL            VCL 604800 259200 0 1729790420 cacheable
--  TTL            VCL 604800 259200 0 1729790420 uncacheable
--  TTL            VCL 86400 259200 0 1729790420 uncacheable
--  VCL_return     deliver
--  Timestamp      Process: 1729790420.342467 0.000214 0.000010
--  Filters         esi_gzip
--  BerespUnset    Content-Length: 162
--  BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
--  BerespHeader   Vary: Accept-Encoding
--  Storage        malloc Transient
--  Fetch_Body     3 length -
--  Gzip           G F E 162 125 80 920 930
--  BackendClose   56 default recycle
--  Timestamp      BerespBody: 1729790420.342510 0.000256 0.000042
--  Length         125
--  BereqAcct      1002 0 1002 237 162 399
--  End

In output I have changed my server's ip with local.ip and my domain with DOMAIN
Any help please?

Why is the redirect not taking place? Is it because the X-Forwarded-Proto is not set to https? Or is the value of the Location header not ok?
There are a couple of scenarios here and I'd like some extra info to approach the issue the correct way.

Hi @ThijsFeryn. Which curl command will help please?

Can you please add the output of sudo varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/'" when you use the IP address to access the homepage. This command will capture the logs for the homepage. I'd like to see what happens in Varnish when your redirect fails. Please attach the full log to your question.

Question updated @ThijsFeryn

May I ask why you need to edit the /etc/varnish/default.vclat all ?

@kekw how I could made the https redirection? In nginx? I did it in Varnish for not any reason.

I use a modified Nginx instance as ssl-offloader to pass the requests to varnish. So the order of requests is like follows: varnish ssl-offloader; varnish; Nginx (magento2)

If this helps you let me know and I’ll post a detailed answer

@kekw you have nginx as proxy or you use hitch also? Please put your detailed answer as it is helpful for all of us I am sure. Varnish and Magento always is a hit

@ThijsFeryn could you please check my sub vcl_recv and make a correction?

Initial observation
Based on the logs I notice that Nginx is still redirecting your request, despite X-Forwarded-Proto: https.
This means your Magento setup isn't processing X-Forwarded-Proto correctly.
Based on what I found on https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/322031/varnish-cache-magento-2-ssl-offloading-x-forwarded-proto-https-vs-ssl-offload, you can either set the Ssl-Offloaded header too in VCL, or re-configure Magento to use X-ForwardedProto instead.
Update based on Nginx configuration
Based on the Nginx configuration you added, I am seeing something kind of interesting. Have a look at the snippet below:
location / {

    # el_GR redirect
    rewrite "^/(?!admin|el_gr|sitemap|stripe|rest|soap|graphql|index\.php)(.*)" /el_gr/$1 permanent;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    add_header Host $host;
    port_in_redirect off;                   # el_GR redirect
    add_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    add_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    add_header Ssl-Offloaded $scheme;
}

In this Nginx configuration snippet, you're setting the X-Forwarded-Proto & Ssl-Offloaded headers to the value of the $scheme variable.
If any of these headers was set in Varnish, Nginx would override the value. Knowing that Varnish Cache only communicates with backends over plain HTTP, my guess is that the value of the $scheme variable will always be http.
This causes Magento to think the scheme of the initial client was in fact HTTP, and will force a redirection.
My advice: remove the occurences of add_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; & add_header Ssl-Offloaded $scheme; from your Nginx configuration and set these values in VCL.

Nothing is changed. I have this in my nginx.conf proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;     proxy_set_header Ssl-Offloaded $scheme; Maybe I need to do this in vcl  file?

Since you installed Hitch in front of Varnish, I don't understand why you would still need an Nginx proxying configuration. As I understand, Nginx is just your web server in front of PHP-FPM. Of course, it could also be your Nginx config that is enforcing the redirect, instead of Magento. Maybe start by adding your Nginx web server config to your question, where we can inspect any potential redirects before inspecting your Magento configuration.

Nginx full configuration updated in question. From where do you get the conclusion that nginx is running as a proxy? Am I missing something please?

You pasted proxy_set_header in the your first comment. That means you're setting a header for a request that is going to get processed. I based my opinion on that. But I'll keep looking into your Nginx config to determine if it's Magento or Nginx that is causing the redirect loop.

In Varnish I have # Add X-Forwarded-Proto header when using https     if (!req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto && (std.port(server.ip) == 443)) {         set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "https";     }' . But magento suggests that # For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'HTTP-SSL-OFFLOADED: https' . So now I use hitch. Where I should set HTTP-SSL-OFFLOADED

Please set it in VCL, in the same logic where you set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto. Just add add a set req.http.http-ssl-offloaded="https"; and set req.http.http-ssl-offloaded="http"; in the right parts of the if-statement.

Check original question please. I updated VCL file. Section with sub vcl_recv and sub vcl_synth. Is this what you mean?

@G.G. looks pretty good. Just one minor detail: please remove set resp.status = 301; from vcl_synth to ensure 302 redirects also work.

@G.G. Does it work now? Can you check how your Magento store is configured to handle offloaded protocols? Does it have awareness for http-ssl-offloaded as you indicated in one of your comments?

No. It is not working. It is giving redirect look. I answered the question with what is worked

With the help of previous answer this is the vcl code which I added and worked:
sub vcl_recv {

    if (!req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {

    if(std.port(server.ip) == 443) {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "https";
    } else {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "http";
        }
    }

    # if accessed by IP
    if (req.http.host == "123.123.123.123") {
        set req.http.location = "https://example.com" + req.url;
    return (synth(301));
    }

    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto != "https") {
    set req.http.location = "https://" + req.http.host + req.url;
    return(synth(301));
    }

and below:
sub vcl_synth {
  if (resp.status == 301 || resp.status == 302) {
    set resp.http.location = req.http.location;
    return (deliver);
  }
}

Where ip:123.123.123.123 put your ip

Very interesting conclusion. Glad you figured it out!  There are ways to further abstract & simplify the if-statement, for example by redirecting if the hostname is n not example.com, ensuring example.com is the only valid host header to be used. But that's more of an implementation detail. The fact that you figured out what caused the redirection is what matters.
